# Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_ping()

Tags: php, wamp

Error

> Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_ping()
>   in C:\wamp\www_server\‌​server.php:2938 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\wamp\www_server\‌​server.php(2926): database->connected(‌​) #1
>   C:\wamp\www_server\‌​server.php(37):
>   database->_construct‌​('localhost', 'root', 'password123', 'ixatdb' #2
>   C:\wamp\www_server\‌​server.php(10): iXatServer->_constru‌​ct() #3
>   (main) thrown in C:\wamp\www_server\‌​server.php on line 2938

Line 2938 below

```
return @mysqli_ping($this->‌​link) ? true : false;
```

Sample of code below

```
public function __construct($host=null, $user=null, $pass=null, $name=null)
{
    if($name != null)
    {
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass;
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    if(!$this->connected())
    {
        $this->link = @mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->name);
        if(!$this->connected())
        {
            $this->error("Failed to connect to `{$this->host}`.`{$this->name}` using password [" . (empty($this->pass) ? "NO" : 'YES') . "]");
        }
    } return true; // Cause I can put it there if I want to
}

public function connected()
{
    return @mysqli_ping($this->link) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Works for me, but as `mysqli_ping()` returns true or false try a simple `return mysqli_ping($this->link);` and do stop using `@` error suppression. If you get an error, fix it.

Comment: @Ivan um what? i think your missing the rest of that "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. " this question contains all that

Comment: Strange none of these worked I am trying to run server.php through php.exe and it keeps giving me these errors no matter what I try thank you for the help above tho @RiggsFolly & Dagon For guiding me to expand on this problem more. :)

Comment: Ah you are using the PHP CLI.

In that case make sure that the `wamp\bin\php\php{version}\php.ini` file that controls the CLI has got the `php_mysqli.dll` activated

Comment: How do I check that? :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly :) thx